# Postmaster Parcels Page is Blank

Tags: postmaster

Good Afternoon, Today I experienced a strange issue with Postmaster 1.4.3 on an EE 2.5.2 site and I'm hoping someone might have some tips to resolve this. What's happening is when I visit my control panel, then pull up the Modules list and click on Postmaster, I'm getting a blank white page. I went to the admin.php file in the root and changed the debugging to 1 and refreshed the page, the following error message was then received:

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'exp_channel_data.field_id_867' in 'field list'

SELECT exp_channel_data.entry_id, exp_channel_data.channel_id,    exp_channel_titles.author_id, exp_channel_titles.title, exp_channel_titles.url_title, exp_channel_titles.entry_date, exp_channel_titles.expiration_date, status, exp_channel_titles.`entry_id`, exp_channel_titles.`channel_id`, exp_channel_titles.`title`, exp_channel_titles.`author_id`, exp_channel_titles.`entry_date`, exp_channel_titles.`expiration_date`, exp_channel_titles.`status`, exp_channel_data.`field_id_867` as 'employee_access_code', exp_channel_data.`field_id_866` as 'assignment_period', exp_channel_data.`field_id_865` as 'employee_title', exp_channel_data.`field_id_864` as 'employee_needing_access', exp_channel_data.`field_id_863` as 'areas_needing_access', exp_channel_data.`field_id_862` as 'branch_name', exp_channel_data.`field_id_861` as 'access_requested' FROM (`exp_channel_titles`) JOIN `exp_channel_data` ON `exp_channel_titles`.`entry_id` = `exp_channel_data`.`entry_id` WHERE `exp_channel_data`.`channel_id` = '121' ORDER BY `exp_channel_titles`.`channel_id` DESC LIMIT 100

Filename: third_party/postmaster/libraries/Channel_data/Channel_data_lib.php

Line Number: 1189
```

I have a staging copy of this same site and the Parcels list for Postmaster is coming up just fine on staging when I pull up the Modules list and click on Postmaster. At this point I made some backups of the main site and attempted to copy over the parcels table from staging. I thought perhaps one of the recent parcels I created caused this and the staging site was two parcels behind, so I took note of the two parcels I would need to recreate then I deleted the exp_postmaster_parcels table from the main site and imported the one from staging. This did not resolve the problem though and I have since restored the original parcels table. I also tried restarting the Apache service and clearing all caches using Tools, Data, Clear Caching. The last thing I have tried so far was to copy over the postmaster folder (/system/expressionengine/third_party/postmaster) from staging to the main site. This didn't resolve the issue either. The error message received seems to be the result of a field Postmaster is looking for in exp_channel_data that doesn't exist. Could I safely create this field in the exp_channel_data table to prevent the error and proceed to the Parcels list?

The good news is I can see my existing Parcels are still working as there is activity in the exp_postmaster_mailbox table from recent Postmaster notifications. I just can't add any new Parcels at this time or edit any of the existing ones due to the database error I'm getting in the control panel when I attempt to access the Parcels list. Any tips or suggestions for resolving this issue and restoring my access to Postmaster in the Control Panel would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The SQL error is due to a channel field being missing. (field_id_867) and as such I don't think its a problem with postmaster directly.

Did you by chance add a channel field on your staging server and not add it on the production server?

Comment: Good Evening Pixldev, I think you might be onto something with your question about staging. I meant to update this question the other day to let the community know that this issue has now been resolved by manually adding field_id_867, field_id_868 and also field_id_869 to the exp_channel_data table.

Comment: I was still puzzled though as to what caused this since there hasn't been a time when I ever worked on staging then imported the staging DB to production entirely or even just the Postmaster parcels table. If I had done this with the Postmaster parcels table and it was referencing custom channel fields on staging that don't exist on production that would totally make sense. At any rate I'm going to go ahead and give you an upvote and I appreciate you taking the time to review my question and reply, Have a great night!